# Flex: Select the first and last item in each row within a wrapped flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'll provide some context.
In this project I need to present some hebrew words with their spanish translation beneath them.
I need the hebrew first and last words of each line to be perfectly aligned.

The problem is that, to align the first words, each first word (.field) need to have `align-items: flex-start`
and to align the last words, each last row need to have `align-items: flex-end`

Is there a way to select each first and last word of each row to apply those rules and have them aligned?
Do you know of another way to achieve the same result, maybe not using flex?

I'll attach the code and an image to illustrate my desired result.
[image: the lines are perfectly aligned]

```css
.hebrew{
    direction:rtl;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 200px;
}
.field {
    display: flex;
    direction: rtl;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.t1 {  
    font-family: 'David';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 6.5mm; 
}
.t2 { 
    font-size: 3mm;
    direction: ltr;  
}
```

```html
<div class="hebrew">
<div class="field"><div id="1a" class="t1">אֱלֹהֵינוּ</div><div id="1b" class="t2">nuestro Di-s[Tdp.],</div></div>   
<div class="field"><div id="1a" class="t1">מֶלֶךְ</div><div id="1b" class="t2">Rey de</div></div>   
<div class="field"><div id="1a" class="t1">הָעוֹלָם</div><div id="1b" class="t2">el mundo,</div></div>   
<div class="field"><div id="1a" class="t1">פּוֹקֵחַ</div><div id="1b" class="t2">que abre(los ojos a)</div></div>    
  
</div>
```

Comment: In the picture it appears to be different amount of fields/text chunks, is that true? ... If yes, then you'll need to wrap each row, or use a script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *fix* it using `flexbox` by *constraining* the width of `t2` with respect to `t1` - add to `t2` this:

```
width: 0;
min-width: 100%;
```

See demo below:

```css
.hebrew {
  direction: rtl;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 200px;
}
.field {
  display: flex;
  direction: rtl;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.t1 {
  font-family: 'David';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 6.5mm;
  background-color: bisque;
}
.t2 {
  font-size: 3mm;
  direction: ltr;
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hebrew">
  <div class="field">
    <div id="1a" class="t1">אֱלֹהֵינוּ</div>
    <div id="1b" class="t2">nuestro Di-s[Tdp.],</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="1a" class="t1">מֶלֶךְ</div>
    <div id="1b" class="t2">Rey de</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="1a" class="t1">הָעוֹלָם</div>
    <div id="1b" class="t2">el mundo,</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="1a" class="t1">פּוֹקֵחַ</div>
    <div id="1b" class="t2">que abre(los ojos a)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="1a" class="t1">אֱלֹהֵינוּ</div>
    <div id="1b" class="t2">nuestro Di-s[Tdp.],</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="1a" class="t1">מֶלֶךְ</div>
    <div id="1b" class="t2">Rey de</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="1a" class="t1">הָעוֹלָם</div>
    <div id="1b" class="t2">el mundo,</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="1a" class="t1">פּוֹקֵחַ</div>
    <div id="1b" class="t2">que abre(los ojos a)</div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <div id="1a" class="t1">אֱלֹהֵינוּ</div>
    <div id="1b" class="t2">nuestro Di-s[Tdp.],</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="1a" class="t1">מֶלֶךְ</div>
    <div id="1b" class="t2">Rey de</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="1a" class="t1">הָעוֹלָם</div>
    <div id="1b" class="t2">el mundo,</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="1a" class="t1">פּוֹקֵחַ</div>
    <div id="1b" class="t2">que abre(los ojos a)</div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Good answer ! I have added more words and a background-color to show the requirement is achieved. Also, as a side note, the first requirement (apply different styles as the element postion in the row) Has been asked a lot of times, and unfortunately it's not currently posible